# Is there a namespace with name "LinqToVisualTree" in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I add `using LinqToVisualTree;` in my project but the program gets an error.

Is there a namespace whith name "LinqToVisualTree" in C#?

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you are using [This](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), which is not a standard CLR namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such namespace in .NET Framework.
But there is third party project called Linq to Visual Tree. This project showing how you may use  Linq API to query the WPF and Silverlight Visual Tree. More details about it you may find on this links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx

http://petermcg.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree-beta/

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/